# Jenkins npm install fails for directory A but is successful for directory B install

Tags: angular, docker, jenkins, npm-install, jenkins-blueocean

My Jenkinsfile is set up at root of a two directory github repo and is designed to install (npm install) packages for two sub directories (dir "frontend" and dir "backend") inside a Docker container. Dir bakcend, a Nestjs app, installs without errors. Dir frontend, an angular app, errors during npm install and gives the following errs: "npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory..."

```
root
-dir backend (nestjs server)
-dir frontend (angular app)
-Jenkinsfile
```

Jenkinsfile snipet:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'node:alpine'
      args '-p 20001-20100:3000'
    }

  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
          steps {

            dir('frontend') {
              sh 'npm install' <<<THIS ERRORS
              echo "install frontend end"
            }

            dir('backend') {
              sh 'npm install' <<<THIS WILL NOT ERROR
              echo "install backend end"
            }
          } 
        }
etc...
```

The 'frontend' `npm install` will result in an error. If I reverse the order and put the "backend" step first, it will install the backend packages without error.

I have another Jenkinsfile with a similar angular app that installs, builds and deploys without err so I do not believe it is an angular/cli issue.

Answer (score 0):

The command `npm install` needs a pacage.json file which is not available in the angular app therefore it is giving an error in angular side whereas in node side , the `package.json` file is already present therefore in node side , it runs succesfully .

To run command in angular side , first you need to run command `npm init` then you can rum command `npm install` .

In **Angular side**

```
Step 1 ) npm init
step 2 ) npm install
```

This will solve your problem .

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching from node:alpine to node:latest and this allowed the npm install to complete.